# WordPress call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class

Tags: plugins, php

I am not the Plugin or theme developer, but after updating the Better AMP , I discovered the following error log. 
What could be the reason? Is there any manual solution to this?

> [24-Apr-2017 19:15:08 UTC] PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects
>   parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Better_AMP' does not have a
>   method '_return_false' in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

Comment: Submit to the publisher and rollback your version to the previous error-free version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with the Better AMP plugin. Best to do is report it to the plugin developer.

There is an invalid filter hook in the plugin, for a quick fix you can try to modify the file `wp-content/plugins/better-amp/better-amp.php`.

Change line 1197 and 1198:

```
// From:
    add_filter( '...', array( $this, '_return_false' ) );

// To:
    add_filter( '...', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Surely I will inform the developer. Well, on updating the `better-amp.php` I am now getting following errors  `PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '_return_false' not found or invalid function name in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298`

Comment: There should be two underscores. `__return_false`

Comment: Awesome! It really worked. Thank you philipp and nathan